# rails_admin - customizing searchable filters based on object_label_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I'm building some kind of a grading system for practice. In rails_admin.rb I have:

```
config.model Student do
    object_label_method do
      :student_code
    end
end

config.model Grade do
    list do
      field :student do
        searchable :student_code
      end
      field :course
      field :category
      field :score
    end
end
```

Using rails_admin gives me a Student filter automatically, however, it searches based on the student_id.
How do I customize the Student filter in Grades admin view to search students based on its student_code attribute? Using searchable like the docs suggested doesn't give any results.

Comment: Did you find the solution for it. Please help me. I want similar functionality

Comment: Hi, no I didn't, however I'll keep this updated in case I find any.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any luck with a solution @AnthonyWijaya?

Comment: Hi @KevinZych. Unfortunately no. I decided to give up on rails_admin and created one from scratch instead. There are just too many problems besides this that I couldn't solve just going through the documentation. I'd advise you to do the same, but maybe that's just me. Good luck with your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the relation between the models `Student` and `Grade`, but I have a model `ConfirmationLetter` where I wanted to be able to search a column `:hospitals` which is a `has_many_through` association but couldn't get any results. I was losing hope on fixing the issue via DSL when I finally found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390218/rails-admin-gem-filter-with-has-many-through-association), so thank you @vinothini and @jxpx777! I confirm that the following still works on RA 2.0.0.beta:

In confirmation_letter.rb:

```
class ConfirmationLetter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bookings, dependent: :nullify, inverse_of: :confirmation_letter
  ...
  has_many :hospitals, through: :bookings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hospitals
  ...
end
```

In rails_admin.rb:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  # Some other configuration here

  config.model 'ConfirmationLetter' do
    # Some other configuration here

    configure :hospitals do
      ...
      searchable [{Hospital => :name}]
      sortable true
      filterable true
      queryable true
    end

    list do
      include_fields :hospitals, ....
    end
  end
end
```

If your object_label_method is a column of the `Student` model, then I believe you should be able to search the Grades list by student code with something like:

```
config.model 'Grade' do
  configure :students do
    ...
    searchable [{Student => :student_code}]
    sortable true
    filterable true
    queryable true
  end

  list do
    include_fields :hospitals, ....
  end
end
```

This also worked with a `has_many` association column. I know it's been 4 years since this was posted but I decided to share my findings here in case someone as desperate as me wants to give it a try!

Comment: I tried with a `belongs_to` association but it didn't work. Good job, anyhow. 