# rails_admin gem filter with has_many_through association

Tags: rails-admin

In my application

> Product has many categories through category_has_products
>
> Category has many products through category_has_products

Initially, I used

at product.rb

```
default_scope { includes(:brand, :categories) }
```

and in rails_admin config set it as

```
field :categories, :string do
 searchable [{Category => :name}]
end
```

This works like a charm. This got into performance issues due to has_many_through(other pages using product details got affected)

So I removed the default_scope from product.

After that, I am getting

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "categories"
```

any idea on how to preload categories?

Note: rails_admin gem version is 0.8.1 only. I am not able to update to latest version 1.X.X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer

in product.rb

```
scope :include_categories, -> {includes(:categories)}
class << self
  alias_method :all_products, :include_categories
end
```

admin_product_config.rb

```
from
    scopes %i[all brandless unmatched matched ignored fresh diy_only]
to
    scopes %i[all_products brandless unmatched matched ignored fresh diy_only]
```

To add filter option

```
  field :categories, :string do
    searchable [{Category => :name}]
  end      
  configure :categories do
    hide
  end
```

Thank you @jxpx777
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1348#issuecomment-39373394